# Avoid event capturing

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymer, web-component, core-elements

I'm trying to avoid [event capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) in a polymer custom element, so I want to trigger an event only when is provoke by the ['items'] contained in the element.

I have two different custom elements. Both custom elements are extending [core-selector](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector).
 One is wrapping the other.

So I have something like:

```
<my-parent-element>
    <parentItem>I'm a parent
       <my-child-element>
           <childItem>I'm a child</childItem>
           <childItem>I'm a child</childItem>
           <childItem>I'm a child</childItem>
       </my-child-element>
    </parentItem>
    <parentItem>I'm a parent</parentItem>
    <parentItem>I'm a parent</parentItem>

</my-parent-element>
```

---

**Custom elements definition**

- `<my-parent-element>` has it's own core-Selected event handler.
- `<my-child-element>` has no script neither event handlers.

**My goal:**

- Only when a item from `<my-parent-element>` is selected the event is
  triggered.
- I want to maintain the components independence, so I would like not to modify the child.

**Situation**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891046/custom-events-in-nested-polymer-dart-ui) I'm stopping the method checking the item received, but I think is not a proper solution...

```
onCoreSelect: function (event, detail, sender) {
                if (!detail.item.classList.contains('child')) {
                   return;   //Dislike!
                }
);
```

...because I would like even not trigger the method.

You can reproduce it in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q0yJSj?p=preview). *onCoreSelect writes details, but only selecting parents should do it. As you can see, when clicking any children it triggers the event.*

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Calling methods only when 'provoked by a item' is done using Declarative event mapping.

Here is the docs and example on it:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping

Comment: That's precisely what I'm using. You can check it in the Plunker.